# Extracting real dates from dates of the week

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I know how to extract a DOW from a date. eg `SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM '2018-04-23'::date)`

But how can I do the inverse? How can I take a series of DOW and convert them into the next date for a given week? (relative to the current week).

```
+-----+---------+
| id  | the_dow |
+-----+----------
| 358 | 1       |
| 359 | 2       |
| 360 | 5       |
| 361 | 2       |
| 362 | 3       |
+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add that number to the start of the week:

```
date_trunc('week', current_date)::date + the_dow
```

As far as I know `date_trunc()` uses the ISO definition of the week, so the first day will be Monday. Using the `isodow` for the extract and the subtracting `1` from that value would be easier.